Will the Europa Clipper spacecraft be visible in 2026 when it flies by Earth again?
The Europa Clipper flight plan includes two gravity assists to get to Jupiter (which I can confirm is monumentally amazing that they managed to time it right) - one flyby of Mars in 2025 and then another flyby of Earth in 2026. Then in just four short years after that it will reach the Jovian system and start doing its job.
Being immensely interested in this particular spacecraft, and wanting to plan ahead a potentially very-fun night for some friends: will the spacecraft be visible from the northern hemisphere at night as it flies by Earth? Given that it'd be moving at escape velocity it'd be going a fair bit faster than the ISS and it would be very fun to sit out all night and wait for it to arrive (since they can pin down the perigee to the minute/second) and watch it fly by.
The primary details are

if it will be passing by the night side of the Earth, since it would definitely not be visible in the day,
if it's bright enough to be seen from the surface - I would guess it would be near sunrise/sunset given that, although it's flying by higher than very-visible Starlink satellites, it also is much larger,
which hemisphere it will be passing over - I myself live in the northern hemisphere and seeing it if it passed over the southern hemisphere instead would be quite difficult.

Is there any available information on this? NASA's mission timeline did not have any.

Tentative yes (w/small telescope & electronic tracking)
The current solution in Horizons is dated Oct 31, 2024. It differs from some of the information in Wikipedia because now it's launch time and actual speed and direction are known.
I exported some numbers and made the plots below.
Since this is so far in the future (~December 2026) and there's a flyby of Mars first (~March 2025), things will change, so my "yes" is tentative.
In amateur telescopes we can often see big communications satellites in GEO about 36,000 km away, and we can see with our eye even small Starlink satellites at several hundred km.

Will the Artemis Gateway Lunar Space Station be visible from Earth by amateur observers?
Is it possible to capture geostationary satellites with DSLR?
At what magnitude would adjacent large geostationary communications satellites see each other?
Observing Geostationary Satellites (also archived)

Right now Europa Clipper is scheduled to pass about 3200 km above the night side of Earth's surface. streaking through RA ~ -20° to +50°, Dec ~ -20° to +18° over 17 minutes.
(a skilled person with a plot on a star map and clock could probably do this by hand)
If we are lucky, JPL will orient those GIANT solar panels (meant to work at 10 AU) to reflect light across a path on Earth so we all get "flashed" (uhoh, I mean "flared"), but if not, I think that at 3000 km the rest of the spacecraft is too small to be easily visible by eye.
A small telescope with a good computer-controlled tracker with the correct trajectory should be able to see it.
Check back in late 2026 to find out what areas on Earth will have visibility at that time. There's that Mars flyby and some trajectory correction maneuvers that will have some effects on the details.


I get a close approach (with the current trajectory data) at ~20:14 UTC 2026-Dec-03 https://i.sstatic.net/QSVZ55kn.png

Here's an estimate of the GP (geographical position), i.e., the location where the body is overhead. It's computed from geocentric data, so it ignores parallax issues. https://i.sstatic.net/A2YUFgJ8.png

@PM2Ring and if you subtract 6378 km from that you get about 3230 km to the subsatellite point on Earth's surface, which is relevant to the apparent brightness of an observer on or near Earth's surface. I think that in December 2026 the distance will still be roughly the same, but the time (and therefore location) could be very different, so I didn't bother with that, but instead said "Check back in late 2026 to find out what areas on Earth will have visibility at that time.

Yes, this is all very tentative at this stage. I expect that the data will be more solid after the Mars flyby.

JPL- or some hypothetical successor- will probably keep the panels edge-on to the path to minimise any possibility of drag. Now is probably a good time to start hunting for a 'scope with tracking software that can lock onto arbitrary orbital elements.
